# Is there a way to put years on X coordinates and other Data on Y coordinates in chart on Win Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I design a meteorological application that needs to read data from files and draw graphics.

The problem is that I'm taking the data, but I can not put them on the chart.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text == temp)
            {
                string selectTemp = "SELECT Temp FROM meteodata WHERE Station= '" + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND Dat BETWEEN '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("_", "/") + "' AND '" + comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("_", "/") + "' ORDER by Dat";

                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(selectTemp, Connection))
                {
                    using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            MessageBox.Show(rdr[0].ToString());
                            chart1.Series["Temp"].Points.AddXY(rdr[0].ToString(), rdr[1].ToString());

                        }
                    }
                }
```

I expected the graph to work, but something wrong with it even does the message work?

Comment: If you are not able to see even messagebox that means you are not getting any data from the database. Did you debug the code? Does the code inside while loop executes?

Comment: It looks like you're `SELECT`ing one column (`Temp`) but trying to read values from two columns (`rdr[0]` and `rdr[1]`).

Comment: I try to see messagebox with values on rdr[0] and rdr[1] but without result ;(

Comment: You don't have `rdr[1]`, just `rdr[0]` (assuming it's not `DBNull`), since you asked for just one field (`Temp`). If this field contains something that translates to a DataPoint, convert it. Or add just the Y Value if it's a non-scatter plot.

Comment: BTW, your query format is badly formed. You should use [SQLiteCommand.Parameters.Add(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteparametercollection.add) to configure it correctly (and, possibly, avoid a disaster).